# how to detect legs with leg_detector and urg_node with visualisation in rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, leg-detector, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i've started the leg_detector and the urg_node with a launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="leg_detector" type="leg_detector" name="leg_detector" args="scan:=scan $(find leg_detector)/config/trained_leg_detector.yaml" output="screen"/>
  <node name="urg_node" pkg="urg_node" type="urg_node" output="screen" args="/most_intense:=/scan">
            <param name="ip_address" value="192.168.0.10"/> 
            <param name="frame_id" value="base_laser"/> 
  </node>
</launch>
```

How can start the leg detection right and how can i visualize them in rviz?
i can see with rostopic echo /scan that the urg_node is publishing the measures and i can visualize them in rviz.
The visualization_marker from leg_detector doesn't publish anything.

i get the warning in the console:

> [ WARN] [1448009011.893469224]: MessageFilter [target=odom_combined ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.leg_detector.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221121/how-to-detect-legs-with-leg_detector-and-urg_node-with-visualisation-in-rviz/) by [kkalicki](https://answers.ros.org/users/25118/kkalicki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-11-19**:
Is there any output in the console? Does `rostopic info scan` show the nodes are properly connected?

**Comment by [kkalicki](https://answers.ros.org/users/25118/kkalicki/) on 2015-11-20**:
I see the urg_node as publisher and the leg_detector as subscriber.
I get the Warning:
MessageFilter [target=odom_combined ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.leg_detector.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Change the `fixed_frame` parameter to reflect the real name of your odometry tf frame. In my case that was just `odom`. Please have a look at your tf treet to find the frame you want. You can then change it using dynamic reconfigure or just add it in the launch file:

```
<node pkg="leg_detector" type="leg_detector" name="leg_detector" args="scan:=scan $(find leg_detector)/config/trained_leg_detector.yaml" output="screen">
    <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="odom" />
</node>
```

If you don't have an odometry frame just use the one of the laser and see if that works for you.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2015-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kkalicki](https://answers.ros.org/users/25118/kkalicki/) on 2015-11-27**:
Thank you, had to change the fixed_frame from leg_detector to the frame_id from the urg_node